# How do I keep an application running after logout?

Tags: macos

I would like my bit torrent client to continue sharing data even after my session times out and goes to the login screen. Running Lion.

Comment: Is there any reason why your session needs to time out?

Comment: My computer is in a public part of my house. I'm happy for my roommates to use it, but I don't like leaving it logged in where anyone who comes in can use it.

Comment: Do you roommates have their own login? If not, you can just lock the computer while staying logged in.

Comment: There is a Guest login but most often I have already logged in and they jump on it after me.

Also, this must be possible. iTunes continues playing when the session times out, so there is no reason Transmission (my torrent client) shouldn't also be able to continue.

Comment: "Session times out" does not have a definitive meaning in OS X, but if that means logging you completely out, there is no way iTunes was still playing. If it on the other hand means just locking the screen, iTunes would still be running but so should your bittorrent client.

Comment: What might have been the case here is that the Mac auto-locked first (keeping iTunes and your bittorrent client running), and then logged you out after an additional timeout (exiting all your apps, including both iTunes and your bittorrent client).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to logout so that another user can use the computer, you can enable Fast User Switching. The other user will be able to use the Mac, while your program still runs.

Answer (score -1):

It isn't possible, but why a logout? Set an active corner on your screen in settings, when you go too that corner with your mouse your display will be shut down but your apps will be running! To activate a hot corner you go to settings/desktop&screensavers/screensaver and in the left corner you see hot corners click that and choose a corner you would like. Click on put display to sleep and your done!

Answer (score -1):

I found a better answer: [Caffeine](http://lightheadsw.com/caffeine/).

Caffeine prevents OSX from going to sleep. I can turn Caffeine on, then go to login screen. Guest account is available at that point, but my own session won't go to sleep until Caffeine is disabled or, if I set a timer on it, it times out.

Answer (score -2):

I don't think it's possible on OSX.
Better way is use transmission-daemon on Linux machine.
And then using remote gui clients (osx/win/linux/android/www) to manage your torrents.

Comment: Daemons also work on OSX